# Trying to put a notification with a service

Tags: java, android

I am currently attempting to have an activity send an intent to a service via

```
startService(Intent i)
```

but whenever I run it it won't work. I believe it is because the method the service is using to receive startService is incorrect, but I don't know what to use in place of it. Here is the activity:

```
package com.example.trackr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class StartScreen extends Activity {

    Intent startMonitor;
    Button newBut;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
        startMonitor=new Intent();
        startMonitor.setClassName("com.example.trackr","StartService");
        startMonitor.putExtra("superAwesomeExtra", "FirstExtra");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void callService(View view){
        startService(startMonitor);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is the service:

```
package com.example.trackr;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class StartService extends IntentService{

    public StartService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent in, int i, int k){
        NotificationCompat.Builder notBuild= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notBuild.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.secret_icon);
        notBuild.setContentText("Now in Secret Mode");
        notBuild.setContentTitle("Secret Mode");
        int notBuildIdentifier=001;

        Intent stopIntent=new Intent(this,CloseScreen.class);
        PendingIntent toStop=
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,stopIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notBuild.setContentIntent(toStop);

        NotificationManager notMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notMan.notify(notBuildIdentifier,notBuild.build());

            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    }
}
```

I know that callService in StartScreen is called because the activity is closing, I'm just not sure why a notification isn't being created. Thanks for all the help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your activities are in the same package, so you can just do

```
startMonitor = new Intent(this, StartService.class);
```

Instead of a blank Intent then setting the class name.

I haven't used an IntentService before, but by the looks of the docs you shouldn't use onStartCommand as the place for your code. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

It looks like you should implement onHandleIntent and have your processing there.

Can you change that around and put a breakpoint in to see if onHandleIntent is being called?

Comment: Also, check if the corresponding `<service>` is correctly defined in the manifest.